# Reverse proxy and Socket.io, failed websocket handshake

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy

I am running a little website using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I've got a node.js application too running on port 3000.

Http calls from the website (client browser) are reverse proxied from `http://example.com/node/whatever` to `http://localhost:3000/whatever`. Everything works fine so far.

The problem is when i try to use socket.io.

I am receiving:

```
    WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=adb9WRpoMFYRoS0vAAAB' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

I am pretty sure, if i am not wrong, that:

It does forward the initial request to my server as the initial request to a websocket server is a standard HTTP request (with some additional headers). IIS does know about that and simply forwards the request. However, upon receiving the websocket request the websocket server sends a 101 response and switch into websocket mode. IIS does not understand the websocket traffic and it is not able to proxy that.

Is there a trick or solution to configure the reverse proxy for the ws:// adresses?

Comment: I've been told that maybe a COMET proxy could help, but i've not idea on how to do that..

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using ? Post 1.0 uses comet techniques (long-polling). Also, looks like you need Windows Server 2012 ? See http://blogs.technet.com/b/erezs_iis_blog/archive/2013/09/16/new-features-in-arr-application-request-routing-3-0.aspx alternatively for you : http://www.guyellisrocks.com/2014/06/using-websockets-when-your-reverse.html

Comment: Also see this related serverfault thread : http://serverfault.com/questions/645077/iis-reverse-proxy-and-websockets-failed-websocket-handshake

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand a bit on my comments. 
As far as I understand, you have several options :

- **bypass the reverse proxy** after the connection (ugly hack if you ask me) : http://www.guyellisrocks.com/2014/06/using-websockets-when-your-reverse.html
- **upgrade** to a more recent version that support native websockets everse-proxying. See this [related serverfault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/645077/iis-reverse-proxy-and-websockets-failed-websocket-handshake) and this [technet features announcement](http://blogs.technet.com/b/erezs_iis_blog/archive/2013/09/16/new-features-in-arr-application-request-routing-3-0.aspx)
- **force socket-io to not to upgrade to websockets** Socket.io (post v1.0) should already handle that I think, that is it should stay in comet/long-polling and not upgrade if the Websocket handshake doesn't work. But you can force it manually anyway.

So, which version of socket.io are you using ? See the [docs](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO%20specifically) for allowed transports (extract below) :

```
io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file
io.set('log level', 1);                    // reduce logging

// enable all transports (optional if you want flashsocket support, please note that some hosting
// providers do not allow you to create servers that listen on a port different than 80 or their
// default port)
io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```